What are the natural and sharp signs between the repeat signs for?


What do the natural and sharp signs in the middle of the repeat symbols mean?

It's a key signature change.  The music before the repeat signs is in B major or G♯ minor; the music after the repeat signs is in G major or E minor.
The naturals are there to cancel the sharps in the previous key signature.  Perhaps it is not strictly necessary, but it is done this way by convention.
The key signature is not inside the second repeated section because (presumably) the key does not change within that section.  This may not be the best way to handle it, but it works.
To see what I mean, consider this, a piece with one section in F and a second section in G:
||: ♭ [-8 bars-] :|| ♮♯ ||: [-8 bars-] :||

Then consider this, which is different from the previous example because the key signature changes back to F halfway through the second section; because you change at the beginning of both instances of the second section, you put the key signature after the repeat sign:
||: ♭ [-8 bars-] :||: ♮♯ [-4 bars-] || ♮♭ [-4 bars-] :||

Back to the first example, if you do it this way, you're signaling a change on the second instance of the second section despite there not being a change at that point:
||: ♭ [-8 bars-] :||: ♮♯ [-8 bars-] :||

Similarly, if you do it this way, you're signaling a change between the first and second instance of the first section, where there similarly isn't a change:
||: ♭ [-8 bars-] ♮♯ :||: [-8 bars-] :||


One explanation for how we wound up with this might be: how would you show a change to C major? In that case at least we need a way to “cancel out” the prior accidentals.

But an obvious question would be: why don't the accidentals come after the second repeat sign? I can't find anything in my Gould ("Behind the Bars") that would require that. Also, Gould only requires naturals if the next key is C major, so in this case, a single sharp would suffice.

@Jos I guess you could write the signature inside the repeat instead, but personally I like how it's written before the repeat here - means I wouldn't have to waste my cognitive capacity on a "shit, sig change, what's this, oh wait, it's actually still the same thing, never mind" on the second run. I also like spelling out the naturals, it's more accessible than relying on the notion that "repeating one of the five sharps automatically cancels the other four that were never mentioned".

@Jos the key signature change is before the second repeat sign because you don't change when you repeat.  I'll add this to the answer.
